# Copying Qt's bin and lib files to Linux bin and lib directory

Tags: qt, libraries

I've downloaded and installed Qt offline installer. It stores it's bin and lib files inside it's own directory, which in my case `/opt/Qt5.4.0/5.4/gcc_64`.

Can I just copy it to `/usr/lib` so I can use it everywhere without need to set linker directory? Will it gonna work properly? Or, may be doing symbolic link wil work?

Comment: Are you going to use them for development?

Comment: If what you mean is professional things, no. I just want use another IDE.

Comment: If you don't have Qt libraries installed from repository then you probably don't have any software that needs Qt. So why do you want to copy them there?

Comment: If i just leave Qt's library and header files there, I have to set linker directory for other IDE that i want to use everytime I create a new project.

Comment: Did you try setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: Sorry, what is that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: It's an environment variable that contain path(s) where the linker will search for libraries.